# void* to vector

Tags: c++, vector, void-pointers

I have a function from some big library. I must pass the argument as void*. I want to pass a vector. I'm passing it using

```
vector<myClass*> myName;

function(...,(void*)&myName,...)
```

Now in this function I want to cast void* back to vector but I don't know how to do this.

I'm trying something like:

```
vector<myClass*> myName = static_cast< vector<myClass*> >(voidPointerName);
```

but I get

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘long unsigned int’

error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>
            ::vector(size_t, const _Tp&, const _Alloc&)
            [with _Tp = myClass*, _Alloc = std::allocator<myClass*>]’
```

EDIT:

What I want to do is pass a vector of pointers to my own class to this function http://ftp.heanet.ie/disk1/www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/microhttpd/microhttpd_10.html, so I must cast it to void* and then cast it back to vector, so the code looks like:

```
    vector<myClass*> v
    MHD_create_response_from_callback (...,HERE_PASS_VECTOR,...);
```

and code for this function:

```
    callback(void* cls,...)
    {
      CAST_CLS_BACK_TO_VECTOR
      ITERATE_OVER_VECTOR
    }
```

Comment: Use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @MariusBancila nope. Don't use a rocket launcher when a fly swatter is enough.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're actually doing something like

```
vector<myClass*> msisdnStructs;
...
function(...,(void*)&msisdnStructs,...);
```

In that case you are passing a *pointer* to the vector. And in the function you are trying to convert that pointer-to-vector to a vector, which will of course not work. You can however dereference the passed `void*` argument (suitably casted), and use that to assign to a reference to a vector (using reference to avoid copying):

```
vector<myClass*>& myName = *reinterpret_cast<vector<myClass*>*>(voidPointerName);
```

Comment: Ok, and now next problem is that for example before function call the result of vector.size() is 2 and in the function 18446726530764637410. The iterator also does not work. The result of printf("%p",&vector) is the same in both cases. How I can use vector in function after casting?

Comment: @fliker In that case I don't think you're passing the array correctly. I suggest you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include that in your question, so we can see *exactly* what you're doing.

Comment: Look on edit in my post and please explain me how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This code of yours doesn't compile:

> ```
> vector<MyClass*> myName = static_cast< vector<myClass*> >(voidPointerName);
> ```

Try to reason *step by step*.

You have a `void*` as input (`voidPointerName`), and you want a `std::vector` back.

The first thing you have to do is to cast from `void*` to `vector*`: you can use the modern C++-style cast `reinterpret_cast` for that purpose:

```
<<vector pointer>> p = reinterpret_cast< <<vector pointer>> >(voidPointerName);
```

Since you have a `vector<MyClass*>`, the `<<vector pointer>>` is actually `vector<MyClass*> *` (I just added the `*` for pointer).

So, the above pseudo code becomes:

```
vector<MyClass*>* p = reinterpret_cast<vector<MyClass*> *>(voidPointerName);
```

You may want to use a C++ *reference* `&` (which offers a value syntax with a pointer semantics), so your code can be slightly modified as:

```
vector<MyClass*>& v = *( << the reinterpret_cast thing above >> );
```

(On the right side of the above assignment, we dereferenced the pointer using `*`.)

i.e.

```
// Final form
vector<MyClass*>& v = *reinterpret_cast<vector<MyClass*> *>(voidPointerName);
```

Comment: Ok the final form works, but now I create iterator vector<myClass*>::iterator it; and when I want to use it myClass* myName = *it; I got seg fault, why?

Comment: @fliker: If you want an iterator to the begin of the vector, you can use `auto it = v.begin();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a1=1, a2=2,a3=3,a4=4;

    std::vector<int> tst;

    tst.push_back(a1);
    tst.push_back(a2);
    tst.push_back(a3);
    tst.push_back(a4);
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = tst.begin() ; it != tst.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
        //ptst.push_back(const_cast<void*>(it));
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    //const void *pitst; --WORKING

    //pitst=const_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<void *>(&a1)); --WORKING

    //std::cout<<"\n"<<*reinterpret_cast<const int *>(pitst); --WORKING

    std::vector<const void *> ptst;

    ptst.push_back(const_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<void *>(&a1)));
    ptst.push_back(const_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<void *>(&a2)));
    ptst.push_back(const_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<void *>(&a3)));
    ptst.push_back(const_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<void *>(&a4)));

    std::cout<<"\n"<< *reinterpret_cast<const int *>(ptst[0]);
    //std::cout<<"\n"<< *reinterpret_cast<const int *>(ptst.pop_back()); --compiler error

    for (std::vector<const void *>::iterator it = ptst.begin() ; it != ptst.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n"<< *reinterpret_cast<const int *>(*it);
        //ptst.push_back(const_cast<void*>(it));
    }
```

...........

**Output:**

1 2 3 4

1
1
2
3
4
..........

*you can replace ..int with your ..class and try*